# how to send mail using phpmailer with smtp.office365.com

Tags: phpmailer, office365

I am using below code to send mail but this is not working for me. Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
require 'class.smtp.php';
$subject="Test PHP mailer";
$message="Hi";

$mail   = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier - TLS/SSL
$mail->Host       = "smtp.office365.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server - smtp.gmail.com
$mail->Port       =  587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server - Gmail SMTP port (SSL): 465 **** Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587
$mail->Username   = "";  // other email address
$mail->Password   = "";            // password
$mail->SetFrom("customercare@test.com", "John");
$mail->addReplyTo('customercare@test.com', 'John');
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
//$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->AddAddress('abc@example.com');
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

It display error message:

Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender SMTP code: 550

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, it's not a problem with the code, but a problem with the permissions for the user your are trying to send as.

You will either need to get the user you're trying to send as to allow their account to be used in such a way, or you'll have to find a different smtp service to use.